# VsCode Running SFDX: Authorize an Org did not open a browser window

Tags: vs-code

Recently, I discovered that I can not Authorize existing Projects or new Projects to my Salesfoce Sandboxes. I did a lot of research, and it looks like this could be an issue with setting a default browser. I tried setting to Edge, Chrome, Firefox, but still a pop up window would not show up for me to authenticate.
Here are a few other things I tried:
-Ensured Pop-ups are allowed for each browser, and even specified salesforce as a trusted site.
-Reinstalled VScode, as well as the Salesforce plugins.
-I also looked under VScode for trusted domains.
Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Does it also happen when you open the command line/terminal outside of VS code and execute the authorize command `sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias my-dev-org`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback. when I run the command you provided, I am still not getting a popup window to show up to authorize.

Comment: If you are on windows, just try setting the default browser to Internet Explorer 11 by going to **Settings (Windows, not browser) > Default apps > Change Web browser to Internet Explorer** and then try the command `sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias my-dev-org` again

Comment: Hi, Thank you again. I did fallow your instruction, but still a new window does not pop up. I tried setting the web browser under default apps to IE, Edge, Chrome, and Firefox. Once I execute the command nothing happens. Really bizarre.